# Get a refresh token using an id token

Tags: auth0

According to the [Auth0 Authentication API docs](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication?http#database-ad-ldap-active-), you can use the `/oauth/ro` endpoint to exchange a username and password for a refresh token like so:

`{
    "client_id": "...",
    "grant_type": "password",
    "device": "my-device",
    "scope": "openid offline_access",
    "username": "...",
    "password": "...",
    "connection": "Username-Password-Authentication"
}`

That works fine. However, for reasons which I won't go into, I don't have a username and password in my context, but I do have an id token.

The docs suggest that I can use the same endpoint to exchange an id token for a refresh token. So I tried this:

`{
    "id_token": "...",
    "client_id": "...",
    "grant_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
    "device": "my-device",
    "scope": "openid offline_access"
}`

But I get a `400 Bad Request`:

`{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "there is not an associated public key for specified client_id/user_id/device"
}`

**How can I get a refresh token from the Auth0 Authentication API using an id token?**

Comment: The id_token to refresh (or access) token method is only for Touch ID authentication on iOS devices, in which case the id_token is a locally generated one, not one you got from Auth0. See https://auth0.com/docs/connections/passwordless/ios-touch-id-swift for the full picture.